# use of ordinal inside Java Enum definition

Tags: java, enums, ordinal

I notice that the [Java Enum Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) states the ordinal method:

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.

I understand all the examples online that suggest not to use `ordinal` to index into an array but an `EnumMap` instead. Particularly [Item 33 of Effective Java](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=Use%20EnumMap%20instead%20of%20ordinal%20indexing&source=bl&ots=yYIfLfr5P-&sig=uDv2JHThXFPNI7LdoYZED3O39JE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0cEUUcmiNom-0QWRvYDAAw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Use%20EnumMap%20instead%20of%20ordinal%20indexing&f=false)
But my question is: is it ok to use it within my `Enum` definition?
For example my code is as follows:

```
public enum Direction {
   NORTH(0, 1), NORTH_EAST(1, 1), EAST(1, 0), SOUTH_EAST(1, -1),
   SOUTH(0, -1), SOUTH_WEST(-1, 1), WEST(-1, 0), NORTH_WEST(-1, 1);

   private final int xOffset;
   private final int yOffset;

   private final static int DEGREES = 360;

   private Direction(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
     this.xOffset = xOffset;
     this.yOffset = yOffset;
   }

  public Position move(Position position) {
     return new Position(position.getX() + xOffset, position.getY() + yOffset);
  }

  public Direction rotate(int degrees) {
     int length = Direction.values().length;
     int index = (ordinal() + (degrees / (DEGREES / length))) % length;
     return Direction.values()[index];
  } 
}
```

As you can see I'm using ordinal() so that I can cycle through the directions (and return the next relevant direction). E.g. rotating 90 degrees from `NORTH` will return `EAST`.

However I know that using ordinal isn't good practice so I wondered if there is a better way to do this whilst still keeping the code size down and maintaining readability.

I'd be very appreciative for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say this is a perfectly acceptable use of `ordinal`. In fact it is, in my opinion, quite neat and simple.

The comments about not using `ordinal` in your `enum` code is merely to discourage you from doing so because most of the time you can use the `enum` itself or an `EnumMap` instead.

Your reference to `EffectiveJava` is warning you against doing this because choosing the correct `int` to use as offset to an array is fraught and generally unnecessary. In your case that doesn't apply because a) You are doing it correctly and b) It is the simplest method to achieve the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: If you read Effective Java carefully (Item 31), you cans see that actually it is advising against using ordinal in this way *because new elements cannot be added to the enum*. In this case too, a WEST_FAR_AWAY(-10, 0) element would break the code. So no, Joshua Bloch would not approve  this code, which is a quick and dirty solution. It is OK (working), but not the best.

Comment: @ibalazscs - In this case adding a new `enum` would not make sense. Your WEST_FAR_AWAY would not make sense at all.

Comment: I can think of many scenarios where it would make sense. For example the move method uses the offset, and a direction with a different offset could be used implement something that is moving fast. Or it could turn out that for some reason SOUTH_WEST should be removed - that would also break this fragile code.

Comment: Somebody dinged me in another answer where I suggested ordinal, and simply referenced "read Effective Java" as an argument.  I would say the best "best practices" are situational awareness and common sense.  If the enums are only being used in runtime code, you're probably not going to be adding elements (its runtime). In db/orm scenarios, you generally want to use the string representation, as its more readable. However, somebody could rename it and blow things up anyway.  Shocker, but its OK to disagree with books here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Your code would break if someone in the future would introduce new members is the enum, like WEST_FAR_AWAY(-10, 0). You need to estimate whether this is a "minor and acceptable flaw" or a "maintenance nightmare" depending on the requirements of your application...

Comment: I'd argue here that it's a minor floor since this isn't what the enum is designed for and it's well documented in my code.

Comment: Then do it this way. If we look at it in a pragmatic way, doing inflexible things inside a class is not so bad as long as the rest of the application is not "infected". In this case, if you change your mind later, you only need to rewrite a single method.

Comment: You can prevent maintenance nightmare by adding proper unit tests. You should also add a code comment explaining the use of `ordinal()`, which in turn makes adding new enum values problematic.

Comment: @TomasKarban Well, I don't think that either unit tests or code comments can replace good design. When you have good design, you don't need to rewrite a lot of code because of a new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> is it ok to use it within my Enum definition?

It's ok to use. But the reasons not to use it and to go for the EnumMap is well stated in the link you provided (Quotation modified as it was referring to the example described in it's section)

> This program works and may even appear elegant, but appearances can be deceiving. Like the compiler has no way of knowing the relationship between ordinals and array indices. If you make a change some where and forget to update it accordingly, your program will fail at run time.

And EnumMap seems quite efficient, if you get to include it in your design for directions.

Comment: I don't see how you'd use an EnumMap in this design though? Would it be a Map<Direction, Direction> (i.e. to next direction). In the example they have herbs that use the Type enums and store Type to the set of actual Herbs. I'm only interested in finding direction that is degrees / 45 (in my case) on from the current direction. I can't think how you'd define a useful EnumMap for it.

Comment: Yes correct. It not on similar lines and I too find it hard to integrate. As you need to get the direction with all the degrees like West should give East after rotation of 180*. Here's is a more like of 1..n mapping. So the current design stands good, but you must be careful while introducing changes as that might lead to complex not easily traceable bugs.